# Find a basis for the subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by the given vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $(1,1,-4,-3)$, $(2,0,2,-2)$, $(2,-1,3,2)$

Now I did this by establishing this matrix
$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-4 & 2 & 3 \\
-3 & -2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and reducing it to:

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & -2 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Given there are three pivots in B, I choose the three vectors in $A$ to be the basis of the space spanned by the three vectors.
 But the book's answer is much different and after playing around I see the book has taken the transpose of the matrix, reduced it, and then used the rowspace of this matrix as the basis of the subspace of interest.
I'm thinking either of these solutions is a correct way, or is the way the book did it the only way?

Comment: What the book did was in some sense to find the "simplest" basis vectors. But as you probably know, most vector spaces have a lot of different possible bases.

Comment: The rank does not change by transposing, so your solution should be valid as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks I checked it twice. Thanks @Peter for your help.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur for your help.

Comment: There are infinite basis for a subspace in $\Bbb R^4$ therefore... you just found one, and the book´s author found other. So there isn´t a unique solution, unless there is another constraint in the question that makes the base unique.

Comment: To check if your vectors $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ span the same subspace as the basis that the author of the book $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, you can try to represent each vector of the author in your basis.  For $j=1,2,3$ find $α_i$, s.t. $$ α_1a_1+ α_2a_2 + α_3a_3 = b_j.$$ This is a good exercise for [changing the basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) of a vector space.

Comment: No I could not do that because the last element in each of my basis vectors is 0, and the basis vectors that the author arrived at has non-zero elements in this fourth position. So what does that mean @P. Siehr?

Comment: Does that mean there there is more than one subspace that these vectors can be a basis for? hhhmmmm. Actually I think what I said doesn't make sense then. There is only one space of dim(3) in $\mathbb{R}^4$ right?

Comment: Ah ok, I didnt read your question  with full attention. There is a difference. Give me a second to formulate it.

Comment: @Bucephalus There are a lot of subspaces of dim(3) in $ℝ^4$.  Lets reduce this to dim(1)-subspaces in $ℝ^2$, because we can draw that ;).  Every line that goes through $(0,0)$ is a dim(1)-subspace of $ℝ^2$.  || About the original question above - I just wrote an answer.

Comment: @P. Siehr. Oh yeah, that makes sense now too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the algorithm to find a basis $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ from given vectors $(a_1,a_2,a_3)⊂ℝ^4$ of $\text{span}(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is:

1. Write the vectors in the rows! of a matrix: 
   $$A:=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ -- \\ a_2 \\ -- \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix}∈ℝ^{3×4}$$
2. Perform row operations on the matrix.

---

Why does this work?

The rows of any Matrix $A∈ℝ^{m×n}$ span a space called "row-space": $$RS=\text{span}(a_1,…,a_m)⊂ℝ^n.$$
Note that $RS$ is a subspace of $ℝ^n$ not $ℝ^m$.

And you can show: If a matrix $B$ is created form $A$ by row!-operations, then it is $$RS(A)=RS(B).$$
Which means row operations don't change the row-space of a matrix.

The space spanned by the columns of $A∈ℝ^{m×n}$ is called column-space and it is a subspace of $ℝ^m$, not of $ℝ^n$.

So what you did is to find a basis in $ℝ^3$ of $$\text{span}( (1,2,2), (1,0,-1), (-4,2,3), (-3,-2,2))⊂ℝ^3,$$
which is not the same as finding a basis in $ℝ^4$ of
$$\text{span}((1,1,−4,−3),(2,0,2,−2), (2,−1,3,2))⊂ℝ^4.$$

(I don't know if row-space and column-space are the correct English terms.)

---

EDIT: I have been thinking if my answer really is correct, after what you wrote. Have a look at the following example

Find a basis of $$\text{span}((1,1)^\top, (2,2)^\top)⊂ℝ^2.$$

Clearly both vectors are linear dependent, and a basis is $((1,1)^\top)$.

The algorithm above - row vectors + row operations: 
 $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix} ⇒ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
Hence $((1,1)^\top)$ is a basis.

Your way - column vectors + row operations 
 $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} ⇒ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
Neither $(1,0)$ nor $(2,0)$ nor $(1,2)$ is a basis.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. Elementary row operations will change the columnspace, but not change the rowspace. So what I  did was actually wrong. Thanks @P. Siehr

Comment: Sorry, @P. Siehr. I was actually mistaken there. My basis vectors do actually have non-zero elements in the fourth entry. I was confusing the column vectors in the matrix B above with the column vectors of matrix A. So now I can verify that the basis vectors from A are a basis for the same space as the vectors that the author arrived at in the back of the book.

Comment: @Bucephalus  I added an example in my answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: No, but if what I did in my example, I do in your example, I would end up with the (1,1) vector. Because I would be finding the pivot vector found by reduction (1,0) and not using that vector, but using the position of that vector in the original matrix to find the basis and as we can see the vector (1,1) is the vector in the same position, so I would end up with the same answer as you got by transposing.

Comment: Tried verifying what you said @P. Siehr by using $Ax=b$ and did not get a pleasing result. I'm heading to bed now. I think I have spent enough time on this one. Thanks for your help.